# Вывести PHP документ

Tags: php

Всем привет! Прохожу курс на Udemy. Сегодня закончили тему PHP. В теме разобрали несколько методов и создали приложение и все, курс закончился..)))

А у меня остался вопрос, ведь тот документ, который мы создали, находится на сервере, а значит пользователь его не увидит и в связи с этим у меня вопрос.

А как этот документ вывести на фронтенд?!) Чтобы он был доступен всем пользователям.

Comment: пользователь и не должен видеть php он должен видеть результат работы php то есть то что он сгенерировал

Comment: php генерирует html и так же соединяется с базой данных и выводит от туда текст и всё ..права доступа создание/удаление файлов ...но его видно не должно быть - это серверный язык программирования то та часть которую называют бекенд

Comment: вот примерно как здесь и отличия только в том что здесь на борту не php а наверно asp.net ...по крайней мере похоже

Comment: Что-то меня терзают смутные сомнения, что на курсе "закончили тему PHP". Там либо и не начинали, либо вы совсем не поняли как работает PHP.